# iphone - Xcode 3.2.3 refusing to run simulator 3.1.3

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a project build to work with iPhone 3* and 4. Base SDK is set to 4. Target OS is set to 3. I have an iPhone 3GS with 3.1.3.

Xcode 3.2.3 refuses to install the app on this iPhone. It refuses also to run the simulator.

WHen I try to debug on the device I get "Failed to upload". When I try to debug on the simulator I get a message telling me that "simulator could not find the sdk"...

Any clues?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling for iOS 3.1.3, using xcode 3.2.3 (and iOS 4 that came with it)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099553/compiling-for-ios-3-1-3-using-xcode-3-2-3-and-ios-4-that-came-with-it)

Comment: Mike, chill out.  He's just trying to help... just like everyone else here.  Does it do this with all apps, or just this app?  Isolate it to either an SDK problem or an app problem.

Comment: I have discovered the solution for this issue, changing the compiler from GCC 4.2 to LLVM GCC 4.2. Don't ask me why, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved partially the issue changing the compiler from GCC 4.2 to LLVM GCC 4.2.

Don't ask me why, but now I can install the application on my 3GS running 3.1.3.

The question is: why GCC 4.2 is not working.

At least the solution for this question is this.

Answer (score 0):

> To expand on Jason Coco's answer: If
>   you go to the Project Info screen and
>   click Build, you can choose what Base
>   SDK to use (4.0) and then scroll down
>   to iPhone OS Deployment Target version
>   and set it to 3.1.3 or whatever.
>   However, you also have to go to the
>   Targets section under Groups & Files
>   (red bullseye) select your target and
>   get the Info build page, and set your
>   iPhone OS Deployment Target there too.

Did you do that also? (from the link posted)